# Responsive design not working well for smaller divices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, screen, media-queries

just Designed a responsive website (www.atdrive.com) its working very fine in screens have larger resolutions, but.. it is not working in for small devices which have smaller resolution
Like smartphones and phablets they have smaller screens but larger resolutions.. for better definition hava look at few screenshots taken from different emulator devices

**Samsung Galaxy tab 2 ||**
*working fine*

[image]

**Samsung Galaxy Note 2 ||**
*working fine*
[image]

**Iphone||**
*Not working fine*

[image]

**Same**

[image]

**Samsung Galaxy S||**
*working fine*
[image]

As you can see website shifted towards left, and i'm not getting any clue how to fix it, i have tried applying viewport but it not worked
and my css are:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 619px)
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px)
@media only screen and (min-width: 250px) and (max-width: 319px)
@media only screen and (max-width: 249px)
```

So please suggest something to fix it or if you had walk-through any similar issue 
[visit atdrive](http://atdrive.com)

Comment: What does your code look like? Try this in the head: '<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0" width="device-width" />'?

Answer (score 1):

Iphone is zooming your web page by default.

Add this code :-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use This chrome extension with chrome developer tools

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh

Comment: If you open Google Developer Tools (F12) and resize the window the dimensions will show up in the top right.

Answer (score 0):

try this meta tag put this `meta` tag insteade of your viewport `meta` tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1170, user-scalable=no">
```

in this meta tag put `"width = your website width"`